# Error while installing octave (mac osX, homebrew)

Tags: macos, octave, homebrew

After seemingly successfully running

```
brew install homebrew/science/octave
```

When I run `octave` from the terminal, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libhdf5.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.1_1/bin/octave-cli-3.8.1
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Closing out this rather obscure question, with mild notes for posterity just in case.

Eventually enough mucking around with homebrew - including manually deleting files noted in `brew doctor` as being potentially problematic - made this problem go away. It seems like homebrew was failing to install hdf5, though not sure exactly why.

Comment: In my case, it is trying to look for libhdf5.9.dylib while my version is libhdf5.10.dylib.I had to downgrade libhdf5 to older version. Although after that it was unable to find /usr/local/lib/gcc/5/libquadmath.0.dylib

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on Mac by running:

```
sudo brew reinstall --build-from-source octave
```

You'll also want to make sure brew is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following environment variables to your bash_profile fixed the problem for me:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:$HOME/anaconda/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.132/compiler/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.132/mkl/lib
```